# ParentComponent always reinitialize when change route in <router-outlet></router-outlet> | Angular

Tags: angular, routes

My structure in my Angular app.
In my `app.component`

```html
<div app-theme>
  <div class="white">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this app component I see login page. After success login I redirect to ProfileComponent.

Then I go to ProfileComponent where have a structure

```html
<div class="sidepanel-body">
  <div class="main-panel-div">
      <app-chat-room-panel [chatObserve]="chatRoomSubject.asObservable()">
      </app-chat-room-panel>
    <div class="center-content">
      <app-header [userInfoObserve]="userInfoSubject.asObservable()"></app-header>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column side-nav-close" position="end">
      <div class="div-lang d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center pointer-hover">
      </div>
      <div class="div-open-panel d-flex flex-wrap">
        <div (click)="navigate('feeds')"
             class="w-100 d-flex align-items-center flex-column pointer-hover mt-3">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Firstly want to show my routing module.

```html
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'registration',
    component: RegistrationComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'profile',
    component: ProfileComponent,
    // canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'feeds',
        component: FeedsComponent,

      },
      {
        path: 'user-info/:id',
        component: UserComponent
      },
    ]
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

As you can see I have a navigation from profile component throught function `navigate` to `feeds` component. And it open in  in `ProfileComponent` in `/profile/feeds` route

```html
navigate(path: string) {
    this.router.navigate([path],{relativeTo: this.route});
  }
```

When I use it I don't have reinitialization again of my ProfileComponent.
But In my header
`<app-header [userInfoObserve]="userInfoSubject.asObservable()"></app-header>`
I have navigation to `user-profile` This user profile open in the same  such `feeds`

```html
 <button (click)="naviGateFromHeader('profile/user-info/personal')" mat-menu-item>User info
          </button>
```

```html
naviGateFromHeader(path: string) {
    this.router.navigate([path],{relativeTo: this.route});
  }
```

After first change route from my header my ProfileComponent start reinitialize during each change route. For example route `feeds` reinit ProfileComponent too. If I don't open
'user-profile' from my `header` (by the way, as you can see `<app-header>` it is a part of ProfileCompoent) it doesn't reinit profile component when change route.

I delete everything what I have in `constructor` and `ngOnInit` in my header. Without result.

ChatGPT advised me to create a `CustomRouteReuseStrategy`

But with out any result.
I tried make route change with `[routerLink]` from html. The same.
Why my ProfileComponent start reinit always after first visit some route from my header?

Comment: i don't see any issue, can you provide a minimal reproduction on stackblitz